# How do I make sure I'm getting the correct number from a file in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a simple batch file to use NETSH to redirect traffic from port 55555 to a port defined in the number after the first 15 characters in a file.

*The echo messages are in my native language (which is why I had to chcp 1252):*

```
@echo off
chcp 1252 > nul
:start
IF EXIST %LocalAppData%\Torifier\ctrl_port (
    SET /p CTRLIP=<%LocalAppData%\Torifier\ctrl_port > nul
    SET /a CTRLPORT=%CTRLIP:~15% - 1 > nul
    IF CTRLPORT GTR 0 (
        SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%CTRLPORT%") do set 
var=%%i
        IF DEFINED var (
            echo Erro na definição da porta...
            GOTO :error
        ) ELSE (
            echo Porta de controle definida como %CTRLPORT%. Continuando...
            GOTO :confirmed)
    ) ELSE (GOTO :error)
) ELSE (
:error
    EVENTCREATE /T WARNING /L APPLICATION /so Forwardnetsh /ID 100 /D 
"Torifier ainda não se conectou – :(." > nul
    echo Torifier provavelmente ainda não se conectou. Aguardando...
    timeout /t 10 /nobreak > NUL
    echo Tentando novamente...
    goto :start
)

:confirmed
    echo Redirecionando todo tráfego local da porta 55555 para a porta 
%CTRLPORT%.
    @rem netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=55555 
listenaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=%CTRLPORT% connectaddress=127.0.0.1
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO error
    EVENTCREATE /T INFORMATION /L APPLICATION /so Forwardnetsh /ID 100 /D "A 
porta do Torifier foi redirecionada para 55555 com sucesso!" > nul
    echo A porta %CTRLPORT% foi redirecionada para 55555 com sucesso!

pause
```

It's set to load in startup but every time it does, it records `-17` to `%CTRLPORT%`, which is obviously not the correct port.

First I tried checking to see if it was a number. Then I tried adding the `IF CTRLPORT GTR 0` clause, but neither solution worked.

Usual output is:

```
Porta de controle definida como . Continuando...
Redirecionando todo tráfego local da porta 55555 para a porta -17.
A porta -17 foi redirecionada para 55555 com sucesso!
Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```

Any tips?

Comment: please post an example of the contents of the ctrl_port file

Comment: You need to enable delayed expansion, `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at the top of the code and then start by referencing `%variable%` as `!variable!` within your `IF`/`ELSE` blocks. You also have some wrapping issues in what you've posted.

Comment: Compo's solution seems to have worked, thanks! Richard, the ctrl_port file is a simple "PORT=127.0.0.1:XXXXX", XXXXX being the actual port, which may be 4 or 5 digits long.